# Button not clicking and getting no errors with Selenium Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

[this buttons are not getting clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZdgI.png)

```
agree_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rightsDeclaration"]')
submit = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="submit-work"]')

def upload():
  agree_button.click()
  time.sleep(1)
  submit.click()

upload():
```

however i noticed that when the function is called, the url gets selected like this:

[Url selected when the function is called](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDfEM.png)

i tried locating with the id, the name , the xpath , everything and nothing

the buttons:

and also i notcied that the page scrolls a bit down (and not clicking ofc) and that's it. what's the problem?

full code:

```
copy_settings_link = "https://www.redbubble.com/portfolio/images/68171273-only-my-dog-understands-me-beagle-dog-owner-gift/duplicate"


def copy_settings():
    driver.get(copy_settings_link)

    replace_image_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="select-image-base"]')

    time.sleep(1)

    replace_image_button.send_keys(Path_list[0])

    upload_check = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        '//*[@id="add-new-work"]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div')  # CHECKING UPLOAD
    while True:
        if upload_check.is_displayed() == True:
            print('Uploading...')
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print('Uploading Finished')
            time.sleep(1)
            break


copy_settings()


def upload():
    agree_button.click()
    time.sleep(1)
    submit.click()

upload()
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem Fixed Guys:
this

```
chrome_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\Username\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data") # Stay LOGGED IN
```

can anyone explain please to me how this code works? it let me stay logged in in the site